# Как запомнить пользователя с SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Как сделать единоразовую регистрацию пользователя в Android?
Человек в первый раз открывает приложение, вводит логин и телефон.
Эти данные нужно сохранить в телефоне (без каких либо проверок на корректность данных) и в дальнейшем обращаться к пользователю по этому логину.
То есть если юзер в следующий раз открывает приложение, ему не нужно снова вводить логин и пароль. 
Сразу открывается основное окно приложения, а не окно с регистрацией, так как его данные уже сохранены в телефоне. Но как это осуществить с помощью Shared Preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для этого используется база данных так как после удаления софта Shared Preference сбрасываются, а так можешь сделать корнивой активити с двумя фрагментами и проверят в нём зарегестрирован ли человек, по типу

```java
if(shared.getBoolean("registered", false)){
  /* Отображаем фрагмент регистрации */
} else {
  /* Отображаем фрагмент основного окна так как юзер зареган */
}
```

Comment: где можно об этом подробнее почитать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui